# How to apply Formik with Chakra in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik, chakra-ui

I am trying to use following example on Chakra but using Typescript

```js
<Formik
  initialValues={{ name: "Sasuke" }}
  onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      actions.setSubmitting(false);
    }, 1000);
  }}
>
  {(props) => (
    <Form>
      <Field name="name" validate={validateName}>
        {/* Trouble in this line below*/}
        {({ field, form }) => ( 
          <FormControl
            isInvalid={form.errors.name && form.touched.name}
          >
            <FormLabel htmlFor="name">First name</FormLabel>
            <Input {...field} id="name" placeholder="name" />
            <FormErrorMessage>
              {form.errors.name}
            </FormErrorMessage>
          </FormControl>
        )}
      </Field>
      <Button
        mt={4}
        colorScheme="teal"
        isLoading={props.isSubmitting}
        type="submit"
      >
        Submit
      </Button>
    </Form>
  )}
</Formik>
```

How do I define "field" and "form" in Typescript ? is there a prop for that ? or should I just define those things in an interface ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was encountering the same problem and gave a look at the source code.
You should be able to use FieldInputProps<T> where T is the value type you expect and FormikProps<T> where T is the type definition of the values you expect.

E.g.

```
{({ field, form }: { field: FieldInputProps<string>, form: FormikProps<{ name: string, surname: string }> }) => {
  ...
}}
```